# How to define a computed property for async associations in Ember data?

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js, ember-data

I am having trouble defining a computed property, based on some async associations, in the object controller. I based my example on some examples I found here and in the Ember docs.

I have three (relevant) models: A `Space` with one or more `Subscription(s)`, which each have a `User`. They are all loaded `async`:

```
MyApp.Space = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  subscriptions: DS.hasMany('subscription', { inverse: 'space', async: true })
});

MyApp.Subscription = DS.Model.extend({
  space: DS.belongsTo('space', { inverse: 'subscriptions', async: true }),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true })
});

MyApp.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I try to compute a property `mySubscription`, which gets the subscription belonging to me from `subscriptions`, in the controller for the space because that is where I have access to the current user through a `mixin`(not particularly relevant for this example).

```
MyApp.SpaceController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  MyApp.CurrentUserMixin, {

  mySubscription: function () {
    var me = this.get('currentUser');
    var subscriptions = this.get('model.subscriptions');
    return subscriptions.findBy('user', me);
  }.property('model.subscriptions.@each')
});
```

This property always turns out to be `undefined` however I try it. I've tried adding `.content` to everything async, I tried finding by `id` and debugged and inspected the hell out of it. Somehow, I am not able to find anything within the array of associated objects. Anybody got an idea how I should proceed?

Comment: Could you define the `subscription ` association on the user?

Comment: Technically, I could, but a `user` might hold `subscriptions` to multiple `spaces` so we would end up at the same point I think (having to search the user subscriptions for a specific space..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed, as Dom Christie points out, the async / sync mismatch. Better than returning in the resolving of the promise is setting a property with an observer like this:

```
updateMySubscription: function () {
  var self = this;
  var subscriptions = this.get('subscriptions').then(function (subscriptions) {      
    var mySubscription = subscriptions.findBy('user', self.get('currentUser'));
    self.set('mySubscription', mySubscription);
  });
}.observes('subscriptions.@each')
```

This way the `mySubscription` property itself becomes a normal sync property.

Comment: Great! This alternative approach fixes the problem.

Comment: It may be worth setting `mySubscription: null` in the controller, to prevent `mySubscription` from being set on the model

Answer (score 0):

`model.subscriptions` returns a promise, so something like the following might work:

```
MyApp.SpaceController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  MyApp.CurrentUserMixin, {

  mySubscription: function () {
    var _this = this;
    return this.get('subscriptions').then(function (subscriptions) {
      return subscriptions.findBy('user', _this.get('currentUser'));
    });
  }.property('subscriptions.@each', 'currentUser')

});
```

(`model` is omitted since you are within an ObjectController)